# OpenLayers 2, GeoJSON can't get coordinates to work

Tags: javascript, geojson, coordinates, openlayers-2

I'm trying to display some polygons on a map, and I'm new to OpenLayers, maps and GeoJSON.

First what works:

```
vector1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON1",
{
    projection       : "EPSG:4326",
    strategies       : [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol         :  new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                            url: "test.php",
                            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
                        })
});
```

This piece of code works, the GeoJSON from test.php shows up on the server, at the position where it should be. But GeoJSON I try to reach is on another server and it throw errors (I know I can set headers and it would work) but I don't want to do it this way.

This doesn't work:

```
var geojs_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
var geojsval= {
                "type": "Polygon", 
                "coordinates": 
                    [[[11.0878902207, 45.1602390564], 
                      [14.931640625, 40.9228515625], 
                      [0.8251953125, 41.0986328125], 
                      [7.63671875, 48.96484375], 
                      [11.0878902207, 45.1602390564]]]
            };
vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON",{projection:"EPSG:4326"});
vector.addFeatures(geojs_format.read(geojsval));
```

This does not work - It displays polygon at a different place even though projection is specified in same way (or at least for me...).

Comment: This is just a guess, since I'm not really familiar with OpenLayers either, but are the coordinates within your GeoJSON ordered as [lon, lat] or [lat, lon]? GeoJSON coordinates are supposed to be specified as [lon, lat], and one common reason for things to display in the wrong place is if they are entered as [lat, lon]. Switching the order here shows a triangle over Ethiopia and Somalia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. When creating OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON you can specific projection like this...

```
var geojs_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
            'internalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
            'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
        });
```

This solved the problem.